# Validation for not a valid Integer value

Tags: java, validation, playframework, annotations, integer

If a `string` comes then these validation is not enough.

```
import play.data.validation.Constraints.Max;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.Min;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.Required;   

@Required
@Min(1)
@Max(500)
private Integer capacity;
```

how i am checking

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = (Set) play.data.validation.Validation.getValidator().validate(object, Default.class);
        for (ConstraintViolation<Object> violation : violations) {
            System.out.println(violation.getPropertyPath().iterator().next().getName());
            System.out.println(violation.getMessageTemplate());
        }
```

soppose user sends `"govind"` in place of Integer value then its give the execution exception

is there any way to do check via `@annotaions`?

or any another suggested way?
i am getting error

> play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException:
>   com.fasterx ml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not
>   construct instance of in t from String value 'govind': not a valid Integer
>   value

Comment: think you have option to use pattern(java.lang.String regex) method to find out whether its string or fully integer. Please look this url for more info:https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/data/validation/Constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

For positive integers try

```
@Pattern(value = "[0-9]+", message = "The value must only contain digits.")
```

Comment: Does the Max work? What happens if user sends 30000? How do you invoke the validations?

Comment: after adding `pattern`  Max and Min also stop working

Comment: And without it? Technically, validation annotations work by throwing exceptions at some point - the question is only which exception is thrown and how it is handled.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. The parameter is called "value", not "regexp": https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/data/validation/Constraints.Pattern.html   Changed the code.